# Why is my PostgreSQL package not working?

Tags: postgresql

I am in a database course and am reading through the book doing the exercises as I go. I have installed PostgreSQL on my computer and created a database book.

I ran the following code to see if the packages have installed correctly like the book prompted me to do and received the following error...

```
Korys-MacBook-Pro:~ KoryHershock$ psql book -c "SELECT '1'::cube;"
ERROR:  type "cube" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT '1'::cube;
```

The books says to see online docs if you receive an error message. I have been looking and have had no luck thus far. I wasn't to move on in the book because I really enjoy this class so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: `cube` is not a standard postgresql data type. Either you are supposed to have installed additional modules, or you're missing creating of the type. If it's just to verify installation, it's probably the former.

Comment: You probably did not create the ["cube" extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html). You need to run `create extension cube;` as a superuser: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html

Comment: KoryHershock$ CREATE EXTENTION cube
-bash: CREATE: command not found

Comment: It says that the create command is not found?

Comment: That is a SQL statement, you need to run that in a SQL client